# Angurlarjs Get External service

Tags: url, service, controller, angularjs, external

I have a problem getting some json information from my service using angularjs.

I have downloaded the example from google and modifed that to get the information that I want from database. but it doesn't seems to be working and I don't know where it's breaking. here is my service.js code:

```
angular.module('productServices', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Product', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://dev.integrator.blondgorilla.com/integratorservice/getproducts?min=0&max=15', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: { ProductID: 'products' }, isArray: true }
        });
    });
```

and controller look like this

```
function ProductListCtrl($scope, Product) {
    $scope.products = Product;
}
```

and the product-list.html page is like:

```
<div class="span10">
    <!--Body content-->

    <ul class="products">
        <li ng-repeat="product in products" class="thumbnail">
            <p>{{product.ProductID}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the main js file is AngularSpike.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('ProsPhere', ['productFilters', 'productServices']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
          when('/products', { templateUrl: 'partials/product-list.html', controller: ProductListCtrl }).
          when('/products/:productId', { templateUrl: 'partials/product-details.html', controller: ProductDetailCtrl }).
          otherwise({ redirectTo: '/products' });
  }]);
```

the code that I used and modifed can be found from

https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git

Thank you,

Kianoush

---

Two problems so far I found:

1- as Marek said .query()
2- I was calling different domain and I should have used JSONP

```
angular.module('productServices', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Product', function ($resource) {
        var test = $resource('http://dev.integrator.blondgorilla.com/integratorservice/getproducts', {}, {
            query: { method: 'JSONP', params: { minid: '0', maxid: '70' }, isArray: true }
        });

        return test;
    });
```

but still I can't see the products

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first issue:

```
function ProductListCtrl($scope, Product) {
   $scope.products = Product;
}
```

and that is that you are assigning $resource to scope instead of some results which can be retrieved by that $resource class.

Try this:

```
function ProductListCtrl($scope, Product) {
   $scope.products = Product.query();
}
```

If there's still something wrong then I can help you if you create running plnkr or something like that.

Comment: Thank you Marek, I have changed that one to query but still it doesn't show me any error and it doesn't show  any products. :(

Comment: I think the $resource is coming back with empty list for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

$resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.so here in `ProductListCtrl` we need callback function to handle this issue.
you can Replace controller using this code:

```
function ProductListCtrl($scope,Product){
    Product.query(function(data) {
        $scope.products=data;
    });
}
```

or you can use this:

```
 function ProductListCtrl($scope, Product) {
       Product.query()
         .$promise.then(function(data) {
           $scope.products=data;
         });
    }
```